# What to call (1 by n) plus (n by 1) operation?

Tags: matlab

I stumbled across an unexpected behavior of the addition operator.

```
a=[1 2 3]; 
b=[5; 7; 11];
a+b
```

Produces

```
ans =

     6     7     8 % a(1)+b(1) a(1)+b(2) a(1)+b(3)
     8     9    10 % a(2)+b(1) a(2)+b(2) a(2)+b(3)
    12    13    14 % a(3)+b(1) a(3)+b(2) a(3)+b(3)
```

This behavior probably falls under the [Add a Vector to a Matrix](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plus.html#bu90zu2) example in the documentation.

> Create an array, A, and add a column vector to it. The vector is
>   treated as though it is a matrix of the same size as A, so that each
>   element in the vector is added to a row in A.

Although, `b` in my example cannot be treated as the same size as `a`. Both vectors must be duplicated.

**What can I call this behavior when I am describing it to others?** None of the definitions of [Matrix Addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_addition) fit. [Vector addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector#Addition_and_subtraction) also has a different definition. The best I could come up with was the "sum of the elements in the cartesian product".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's called binary singleton expansion. Starting with R2016b, MATLAB does it automatically with standard operators. See `bsxfun` for more details.

Comment: I guess bsxfun is where I would look if I wanted this behavior and I didn't know it existed. But it is not at all an intuitive place to look if you stumble across the behavior and are trying to explain it. :P

Comment: Also called implicit expansion... here's a blog post from Mathworks https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/11/10/more_thoughts_about_implicit_expansion/

Comment: Oops, here's the original. http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/

Comment: Also called _broadcast_ in other languages (Octave, Numpy)